# next.js Ensure that the state value changes when the queryString, which is the state value, is changed in the url

Tags: next.js

In the next.js environment, I want to change the query string value managed in the state directly in the url and press Enter so that the corresponding state value is updated.

Previously, I used useEffect to change the state url query value, and when I pressed Enter, the state value was called with the url query setState value.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this in the Next.js environment other than useEffect, or if there is a good library that can be used to create it.